# How to connect MySQL Database in django 1.10.6

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

```
import MySQLDB as Database
```

> File "c:\pythonprojects\env\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.2-py3.6-win32.egg\mysqldb__init__py", line 22

```
 raise ImportError, "This is MySQL Version %s, But _mysql is version %r"
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: We need more info about your problem. Post your code or just describe better your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have pymysql installed. Then in settings.py do this

```
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except:
    pass

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'db-name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Brother. Its Work.

Answer (score 0):

i) First you have to install the mysql server in your machine, if you already have mysql server up and running then jump to next step.

ii) Create a user in mysql (you can use the root user, but I would suggest create a separate one) you can refer mysql documentation for creating a new user. Let, you have created a user with:- username = **testuser** , password = **testpass@123**

iii) Create a database in mysql , let named it **testDB**

iv) Now you have to install mysqlclient-python, to install it from PyPI you can do so by typing **pip install mysqlclient** (by default pip the python package manager points python2 series if you are setting up your django project on python3 then you have to use pip3) for more information on how to install mysqlclient-python on your particular OS you can refer this link: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

v) Now In settings.py under key DATABASES make these changes:

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # for mysql engine
      'NAME': 'testDB',
      'USER': 'testuser',
      'PASSWORD': 'testpass@123',
      'HOST': 'localhost', # if you want to run your project on your localmachine 
 }
    }
```

vi) Now change your working directory to your django project directory: " cd yourDjangoProject" and run these django commands

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

Now I hope that above django commands will run successfully and you would be able to use to your mysql database in your django project.